# How do I reload the page after making changes to JavaScript code on source panel of chrome dev tool

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was profiling bbc page and I noticed some jankiness. I got to the culprit JavaScript file and it had an observer on scroll. I made the changes. However when I reload the page all my changes are gone.

I could have used workspaces but since I do not have bbc code I can't use it.

My question is after making local changes to the file how do I tell chrome devtool to use this changed file and then reload the page so that I could do performance profiling again.

Comment: You can use an extension. There might be some already.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is [in development](https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/926192723241058304) as a Local Overrides experiment. However, it is not yet stable (some testers reporting it simply crashes the browser) so using the experiment as it is now is not recommended. As it is, in Stable Chrome DevTools there is no functionality for this built in.